# How to randomize 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, random

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
{
    int r = rand() % 3;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int temp = mati[i][j];
        mati[i][j] = mati[r][j];
        mati[r][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here I have a 2d array named `mati` and I want to randomize its elements but I don't know how?

Comment: Is your array 2D array always 3x3?

Comment: oh sorry yes ı forgot to say that yes it is btw

Comment: Why not pick a random column as well as a random row - but both within the inner loop. Presumably you initialised the array and want to swap its elements around.

Comment: it has to be different everytime ı choose if ı try to sellect random row and collum it can be same after 5 turn

Comment: Search on SO for 'fisher-yates shuffle'.  That ensures that the resulting shuffled matrix is fairly shuffled (so that some permutations are not more likely than others).  Treat your 3x3 matrix as having size 9.  Generate random numbers `x` in the range `0`..`8` and then use `r = x / 3; c = x % 3;` to give the row and column number.

Comment: ı have already searched for that thx but ı didt understand why ı have to use x/3 and x%3

Comment: You'd use the `r = x / 3; c = x % 3;` expression to get a row number in the range 0..2 and a column number in the range 0..2 from a value in the range 0..8, so you can then use `x[r][c]` to identify an element of the matrix at random.  You could also reverse the expressions: `r = x %3; c = x / 3;` without problem (while you're doing random access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int n = rand() % 9;
        int temp = mati[n / 3][n % 3];
        mati[n / 3][n % 3] = mati[i][j];
        mati[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```